# 301 Redirect htaccess Change URL Structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all pages from a Wordpress multi-site installation to another Wordpress installation - e.g. `website.com/blog/blog/page` to `website.com/our-blog/page`

Using `redirect 301 / http://www.website.com/our-blog/` doesn't work because the visitors are redirected to `website.com/our-blog/blog/blog/page`. Does anyone know how to remove the `/blog/blog`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/blog/(.+)$ http://www.website.com/our-blog/$1
```